# SQL query subtable in columns from main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables with a main table with a unique UUID as index and a sub-table containing the languages of 1 row of the main table.

E.g.
table_1

| uuid | code |
| --- | --- |
| 111-etc | 123 |
| 222-etc | 321 |

table_1_lang

| uuid | lang_code | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111-etc | en | english 123 |
| 111-etc | de | deutch 123 |
| 222-etc | en | english 321 |
| 222-etc | de | deutch 321 |

I want to create a query that has a result of 1 row per main table (table_1) and add extra columns for each lang_code.
I've managed to create something close to the end result with hard-coded lang_code's but the _lang table can be dynamic (extra languages) so this is not what I want.
The result must be like:

Result:

| uuid | code | title-en | title-de |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111-etc | 123 | english 123 | deutch 123 |
| 222-etc | 321 | english 321 | deutch 321 |

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwdRD.png)

Edit: As image because the layout of the tables seemed to be screwed up

Thanks for the help.

Comment: SQL is too general as tag. You might need to apply tags to indicate your platform

Comment: Yes, perhaps the dbms you're using has PIVOT? With no other tag than <sql>, expect ANSI/ISO SQL answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to convert your defined row into a column name using stuff and then using pivot to fulfill your requirement.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols =  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('title-'+lang_code) 
                    from table_1_lang
                    group by lang_code                    
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
        print @cols
set @query = N'SELECT uuid,code, ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select t1.uuid,t1.code,concat(''title-'',t2.lang_code) as lang_code,t2.title from table_1 t1
                inner join table_1_lang t2 on t1.uuid = t2.uuid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(title)
                for lang_code in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

print @query
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Hi Malvik, thx for your answer. I will test this tomorrow morning. I let you know if its working

Comment: Hi, I've just tested your answer successfully. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @pietvp Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` the table_1_lang table once for each language:

```
select t.uuid, t.code, len.title, lde.title,
from table_1 t
left join table_1_lang len on t.uuid = len.uuid and len.lang_code = 'en'
left join table_1_lang lde on t.uuid = lde.uuid and lde.lang_code = 'de'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
That would be the 'hard-coded' variant but the case is that the language table could contain these languages or languages quite not known yet 'nl', 'fr' etc.
So for each language in the sub-language table I want to have a column.